# "Questions with new activity" in custom filters don't get new/read indicator as expected

Tags: bug, live-refresh, custom-filters

When you view the page for a custom filter, new questions with activity accumulate at the top of the page:

[image: Stack Overflow custom filter - questions with new activity]

If you click to show those questions, they don't get the red circle indicating they are "new":

[image: Stack Overflow question in custom filter page without new indicator]

However if you later click to your custom filter page, that question will be marked as "new", despite the fact that you already saw them in the custom filter page:

[image: Stack Overflow question in custom filter page with new indicator]

This is the exact opposite of the behavior that I would expect.  I would expect that when new questions are loaded into the page via the "questions with new activity" link, all those questions would have the red circle indicating they are new and unread.   Later when you come back to the page, those questions would no longer be marked that way.

Comment: Related, but not identical bug report: [New questions matching filter are not marked with circle icons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385760/578690)