# New questions matching filter are not marked with circle icons

Tags: bug, live-refresh, custom-filters

I see that a filter (here, `python`) has `New questions match this filter` blue circle icon next to it:

[image: custom filter with new questions shows blue circle icon next to it]

When I click on this filter, I expected new questions to have circle icons next to them. I could see the new questions, as indicated by the time posted/modified. But they did not have circle icons next to them:

[image: clicking on the custom filter does not show circle icons next to new questions]

I observed this behavior on Stack Overflow in both Google Chrome and Firefox.

**SEE ALSO:**

Here is an example that shows how the circle icons next to questions *used* to work previously:
["Questions with new activity" in custom filters don't get new/read indicator as expected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371895/578690)

**Note that my question is entirely different from the above question in that I do not see the circle icons at all.** To quote the above question:

> However if you later click to your custom filter page, that question will be marked as "new", despite the fact that you already saw them in the custom filter page

I **do not** see the questions *'marked as "new"'*.

Comment: Do not post duplicate on purpose please. The bug has been already reported, nothing else we can do. You can bump the original report by valid edit or a bounty, but not by posting whole new bug report, reporting the same thing again.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I edited my question, showing how it is different from the one marked as dupe target.

Comment: My question turned out to be a duplicate of these: MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383520/578690 , MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421294/new-activity-indicator-has-disappeared-from-questions-on-custom-filters-pages . I think that my question is still useful to help others find the proper dupe targets, as these are hard to find (too me a while).